# PHP counter in Javascript for loop

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a javascript for loop in which a php variable is counting (phpVar++) each loop.  However, the variable, which starts at 0, always ends up being 1, even though the loop loops multiple times.

Is this not possible?

```
<script>
    <?php  $totalMarkers=0; ?>
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      <?php $totalMarkers=$totalMarkers+1; ?>
    }
    <?php echo $totalMarkers ?>   //this always prints "1"
</script>
```

I'm trying to do this so that I can print $totalMarkers in different places in the Body of the HTML.

Comment: Duplicate of so many questions that I've lost count.

Comment: PHP/JavaScript doesn't work that way.  You can't do that.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg  I did multiple searches before posting and didn't find anything.

Comment: @swl1020 Here's one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100633/change-php-variable-based-on-javascript-value . Google for "change php variable in javascript" or similar to find more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript is executed on the client computer, PHP is executed on the server. So, your loop does not run until the page is completely loaded in the user's browser -- at that point, no PHP will be executed.

When that page is rendered, this is the process:

`<script>` <-- gets output literally

`<?php  $totalMarkers=0; ?>` <-- has no output

`for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {` <-- is output literally

`<?php $totalMarkers=$totalMarkers+1; ?>` <-- has no output

`}` < -- is output literally

`<?php echo $totalMarkers ?>` <-- outputs 1

`</script>` <-- is output literally

If you were to view source, you would see this:

```
<script>
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    }
    1   //this always prints "1"
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

PHP runs on the *server*. JavaScript runs in the *browser*.

Your server runs the PHP, and will then send this to your browser:

```
<script>
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      }
    1</script>
```

The only way JavaScript can affect PHP is with AJAX or similar.

Answer (score 3):

PHP runs server-side, JavaScript runs client-side (ignore Node.JS et.al.)

The HTML your browser receives will look like:

```
<script>
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    }
    1   //this always prints "1"
</script>
```

So, I'm not sure what you want to accomplish here, but you have to keep in mind that PHP and JavaScript can not interact directly.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mix PHP and JavaScript like that.  It doesn't work that way.

The PHP is ran *before* the JavaScript is.  So, the lines:

- `<?php  $totalMarkers=0; ?>`
- `<?php $totalMarkers=$totalMarkers+1; ?>`
- `<?php echo $totalMarkers ?>`

are ran *before* your browser sees it.

Your browser just sees:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
}
1
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible - not without using a bunch of AJAX which seems totally inappropriate for you. PHP is executed way before any JavaScript can be executed. PHP is Server-sided, JavaScript is client-sided. Thus, JavaScript can not control PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. PHP is a Hypertext Pre Processor. It is executed **before** any Javascript code. The code you actually have takes $totalMarkers and initializes it to 0. Then it adds one and then it echoes... It will always be "1" !

You need to count using a Javascript variable then send it to the server if you want to manipulate it with PHP.